# remove commas from string only from digit value in php

Tags: php, regex

Below is my PHP String

```
$string = '"2015-10-04","Answer","Kumma","wikia","Kumm","890, 609","17,214","15,705", "14,538","1.93","91.23","92.57","4.00","58.15","50.88","7.27","12.50","25","0.17","11,840","81.44"';
```

I jsut want to remove comma's from digits values like 14,538 ,11,840 etc . But it will not remove any other comma Please help me thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
preg_replace('~(?<=\d)\h*,\h*(?=\d)~', '', $str);
```

Comment: Thanks , It's working well just a need to make it for 1 more case now it's working fine for 17,214 but not working for this type of digit 890, 609 , Please help me for this as well thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick help now it's working fine . If further I need help on this I will paste comment here . Thanks ... :)

Comment: accept if this works.

Comment: Actually I am new on this forum to post my issue I am already searching for how I can vote you but still unable to fine can you give me hint on this .  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try `preg_replace()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$string = '"2015-10-04","Answer","Kumma","wikia","Kumm","890, 609","17,214","15,705", "14,538","1.93","91.23","92.57","4.00","58.15","50.88","7.27","12.50","25","0.17","11,840","81.44"';

preg_replace('~(?<=\d),(?=\d)~', '', $string);
```